# How to make dynamic urls from base urls in a json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am making an ajax call to load a json file which has all my REST API urls in it. For urls which are static for eg: `/read` things work fine.

How can I have a placeholder for a dynamic url in the json file 
For eg: `read/{article_id}/edit/{sub_article_id}` . Here how can I replace `article_id` and `sub_article_id` in my javascript code after loading the base urls from json file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a generic config of how your api variables and their values:

```
paramConfig = {'{article_id}':    "Your Article Id",
               '{sub_article_id}':"Your subarticle id"
                ...
                ....};
```

All possible dynamic variables should be set in above config. Then use below function to get the parsed url :

```
function getAjaxUrl(rawUr){
        for(var param in paramConfig){
            rawUrl = rawUrl.replace(param,paramConfig[param]);
           }

        return rawUrl;
}
```